# Trying to override a react mui version 4 select style with whiteSpace="normal". what I am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

https://v4.mui.com/system/display/#api

mui shows I should just be able to override the style on the component level.  But no matter what I try (overriding the style, creating a new theme) I get white-space=nowrap...

[image]

Here's my code...

```
    <Select
      MenuProps={{
        className: classes.selectMenu
      }}
      classes={{
        select: classes.chrisHelp
      }}
      whiteSpace="normal"
      multiple
      required={true}
      input={<Input  />} 
      renderValue={selected => selected.join(", ") }
      onChange={updateFieldHandler("issue_description")}
      inputProps={{
        name: "issue_description",
        id: "issue_description",
        value: (typeof submissionData?.issue_description === 'string' || submissionData?.issue_description instanceof String) ? submissionData?.issue_description?.split(",").map((description) => {return description}) || [] : (typeof submissionData?.issue_description !== 'undefined') ? submissionData?.issue_description || [] : []
      }}
    >
```